# unexpected identifier error in jquery

Tags: jquery

Whats wrong with this jquery?

```
$(function(){
    totalwidth = $(window).width();
    if ( totalwidth < 1295 ){
        $("#maininvite").width(((1295 - totalwidth)x100 / 1295) + 50 +'%');
    }

});
```

the purpose of it is to make the calculations and then add it to the already set width of 50%.

it gives me unexpected identifier in the chrome inspect

Comment: What is the full error it gives? I'm betting it's the fact that you're using `x` for multiplication, and not `*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this line is your issue

```
x100
```

supposed to be

```
*100
```

Better calculate the value and then concatenate to the `'%'`

```
$(function(){
    totalwidth = $(window).width();
    if ( totalwidth < 1295 ){
        var newWidth =  (((1295 - totalwidth) * 100)/1295 ) + 50; 
        $("#maininvite").width( newWidth + '%');
    }

});
```

Comment: are you serious ? x instead of *.how it can happen!